# Visual Studio AxWmpLib change language track

Tags: visual-studio-2010, audio

I am currently writing a program in Visual Studio 2010 C#.
I am working with AxWmpLib, library in charge of Windows Media Player.

I have a video with two tracks, Spanish and English (it shows perfectly in Windows Media Player, I can change language with out problems).

When I try to play in my application, take original track. I was looking for how to create a button to change the language, but I found nothing thats works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem

IWMPControls3 ctl3 = (IWMPControls3)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols;
ctl3.currentAudioLanguageIndex = 1;

I found it in spanish forum of msd
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/8ef567d3-6e29-4be3-81d1-132b32bfeff0/axwmplib-dos-idiomas?forum=vcses&prof=required